# How to access Amazon AMI ec2 instance in GUI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I am having an Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1 (64 bit) ec2 instance, I am accessing it using putty by providing the `ppk` file and ip address. But it connects me to the terminal, is there any way I can access it with GUI ?

Comment: Not in general. You would need an X server running on the VM (which most AMIs don't do), set the firewall rules to allow you to connect and then connect using a suitable client.

Comment: vnc server + ssh port forwarding is one of the best options you have, search in google for these topics

Comment: @akostadinov Can you please share the link to some good tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very brief answer. It is not amazon linux specific because I don't use it but should give you enough hints because it is Red Hat based AFAIK.

Basically you need to install the GUI you want to use (xfce, gnome, kde, etc.) and vnc server. try `yum search vnc` and `yum search gnome` to find out what packages do you need to install.

You then start vnc server on the machine. You do the above through command line console. If it works for you you may make VNC start with machine boot.

I don't know which tutorial is good for putty port forwarding because not using windows but this looks promising to me: http://martybugs.net/smoothwall/puttyvnc.cgi

With linux (perhaps if you install cygwin on your windows that will be possible for you as well) one usually can start a remote vnc session with automatic port forwarding like:
`vncviewer -via <machine you try to connect> <screen number, usually :1>`